# Does async IO use less energy than multithreading?

Tags: asynchronous-programming

Given the same application written with multi-threading and async IO, will async IO use less power on a computer?

Comment: Not enough that you care.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SoftwareEngineering!  It's kinda hard to guess what you're talking about since both "_multi-threading_" and "_async IO_" are very general terms for things that can be implemented in all sorts of different ways in all sorts of different contexts on all sorts of different devices.

Comment: see **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)**. "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: @gnat: Here's a better one: [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742)

Answer (score 3):

Overhead from threading-based solutions comes from two factors:

1. Context switching between threads is performed by the operating system. This implies context switching between user and kernel mode, and has higher overhead than equivalent switching between tasks by a scheduler within the application (e.g. “green threads” or an async executor/event loop). Furthermore, it is possible to use a cooperative multi-tasking approach within an application, whereas the OS has to use pre-emptive switches for security reasons. This could interrupt the application at a bad moment. A cooperative approach lets a task suspend itself at a moment where it has to wait anyway, reducing overhead to potentially zero. But this overhead is typically small anyway, so let's disregard this.
2. Each operating-system level thread has some memory overhead. It needs to allocate its own stack space, usually a few KB. This overhead can turn into a hard limit when an application tries to start tens of thousands of threads of which most will just sleep until some I/O event occurs. In contrast, languages with async systems can represent the task state as an object or state machine, which can require far less space (often just a few 100 bytes or less). This makes it feasible to have millions of pending tasks. Memory is important because there's only so much RAM you can economically pack into a single server.

What does this mean for power consumption? Async IO is not inherently more power-efficient, unless an event-based system replaces anti-patterns such as spin-wait loops. However, async approaches make it possible to handle way more pending tasks on a given system, thus allowing for higher density and more efficient use of a given hardware. This depends on the task at hand, of course. This won't matter for CPU-bound tasks like numerical simulations. However, it matters a lot for typical web applications or microservices, where a request often spends most of its duration waiting for *another* service to respond. In that context, higher density  can indirectly lead to more energy efficiency. If I need five servers to run a thread-based workload, but can get by with only four with an async-based implementation, one server can be turned off and doesn't consume power.

Comment: How does this play out on a single machine?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Depends on how you view it. At the same throughput, event-based instead of thread-based software might have a tiny bit less CPU overhead. However, being able to juggle more tasks at the same time (due to less RAM consumption) could move CPU load closer to 100%, which could increase power draw non-linearly. But this would depend a lot on the specific hardware.

Comment: +1 Good answer (better than mine) but I think the last sentence downplays the potential impact.  I think it's more like 10 servers instead of 100 for a lot of common IO-bound scenarios.

Comment: I did a little poking around and it seems that typically draw to load is more or less linear.  There's an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1121696/does-a-cpu-consume-less-power-when-it-is-idle) for a different question but touches on the main points.  This seems to be logical: CPUs aren't really like variable speed motors.  They are either executing instructions or not.  I suppose heat could be a factor in a high utilization scenario.

Comment: @JimmyJames It's not quite so easy. CPUs scale voltage and frequency dynamically. Power draw is directly proportional to the square voltage. However, voltage, frequency, and temperature are all related in practice. There's a [nice academic paper “Energy/Frequency Convexity Rule”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4655) showing analytically and experimentally that there will be some frequency that minimizes energy usage for a given task+CPU, i.e. doing the same work more slowly can lead to significant savings. Of course, the workload of a server gives a lower bound for how slow we can go.

Comment: @amon Thanks for the link, I think the relevant conclusion is "this implies that there
exists an operating frequency, which is neither the maximum nor the minimum
operating frequency, at which the CPU would execute a code sequence on the
top of the OS in the most energy efficient way."  It would seem to me that allocating your load to hit that sweet spot is going to be a lot easier if you can get each thread in your system close to fully busy.

Answer (score 0):

For IO-bound work, asynchronous IO makes more efficient use of the hardware on a system than using separate system threads for the same purpose.

So if we can use async-IO to reduce the number of servers needed to run web server farm, I need less CPUs which means less power.  So I would say 'yes' at a high level.  The amount of saving is going to depend on how the load ratio you can get versus multi-threading.  If you are running at the scale of Google or AWS, it could be significant.

Comment: This doesn't follow.  Working your hardware harder increases energy usage; you only have to listen to your fans to know that.  The actual outcome, energy-wise, is unclear without more information.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Really, you think 100 machines use the same amount of energy as 1 of the same make and model running at the same load?

Comment: Ah, but you didn't make that assertion in your answer.  Don't move the goal posts; say what you mean in your answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Huh? "less CPUs which means less power." What does that mean to you?

Comment: Fine.  I dispute that assertion.  As with all things performance, the way you find out is to *measure, not guess.*

Comment: Anyway, I didn't say "the same load," and neither did you.  Changing the way you do I/O is going to change the load.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm trying to simplify it to something really basic since you seem to not understand and I'm not sure why.  CPUs use a baseline of power.  If, as you seem to assert, the amount of power is proportional to the work being done, if I can get the same work done with less CPUs, I've saved on overhead.

Comment: Yes, but you do have to reduce the number of CPU's, and the CPU's would work harder with async I/O.  So you cannot predict with any confidence that merely switching to async I/O would reduce electricity consumption, in this scenario or any other.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why don't you think that is clear?  Would you like me find you an article or presentation on the subject?

Comment: Sure, I'll have a look.  But the article would have to state that going to Asynchronous I/O categorically reduces electricity use without taking any other factors into account.  That is, after all, the question that the OP asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "The amount of saving is going to depend on how the load ratio you can get versus multi-threading."  I never stated it was guaranteed.

Comment: But you imply that there *is* energy savings of some kind.  I'm saying that not even that is guaranteed.

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/kotlin-async/ He covers the basic concept I am talking about around 4 minutes in.

Comment: Where is the part where he talks about energy usage?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If one company can save energy this way, it saves energy QED.  I explicitly point out that scale is a major factor.  I'm not going to argue strawmen.

Comment: { shrug } Since amon answered in essentially the same way you did; I'll accept your premise, which is that, *if you make some (reasonable) assumptions about the way server farms work, you can possibly make some scaling gains there.*  Not the question the OP asked, but oh well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you are missing that a large part of why asyncio has become so common is because it saves on resources that are wasted when blocking.  Energy is probably not primary but it is part of the savings (including cooling costs.)  Insulation doesn't guarantee a lower heating bill but that's mostly the point of it.

Comment: I get it.  Like insulation, `async` doesn't guarantee a lower electricity bill, either.  `async` operation on a single computer may actually *increase* electricity consumption, because it makes the CPU more busy.  In a way, the OP is asking the wrong question; productivity (in whatever way you measure that) is almost certainly more important than a few cents worth of electricity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "may actually increase electricity consumption, because it makes the CPU more busy"  I don't think I follow.  Are you suggesting that the CPU energy consumption is not linear to the load (ignoring overhead)?  E.g. running a CPU at 80% capacity for 5 minutes uses more energy than running it at 40% for ten?  If you have 100K requests to handle every minute, using asyncio isn't going to change that.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that running a CPU at 80% capacity for 5 minutes uses more electricity than running it at 40% for the same five minutes.  The OP didn't state any conditions about the amount of work produced, only about the amount of electricity consumed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And why would you expect the workload to double when there is nothing suggesting that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how'd you understand the question as something answer-able?  I mean, I interpreted **"_async IO_"** as "_the practice of allowing a thread to continue with other work while input/output operations resolve_" and **"_multithreading_"** as "_the practice of using multiple threads_", so to me, the question was incredibly vague to the point of being meaningless.  The two practices often co-exist, but they don't have to, nor are they alternatives.  But I get the impression that you were able to interpret the question as having some specific meaning, just.. how?

Comment: @Nat How do you figure they are not alternatives?  It's very common to replace multithreading with asyncio.  There are whole frameworks based on the idea e.g. https://netty.io/

Comment: @Nat Here's [some discussion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191443(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#threads) about asynchronous io and how "The async-based approach to asynchronous programming is preferable to existing approaches in almost every case. In particular, this approach is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations..." [BackgroundWorker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks) " ...to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread."

Comment: @JimmyJames: They're not alternatives in that they're just different qualities, sorta like.. the font-family "_Times New Roman_" and the font-size "_11_" aren't alternatives.  Rather, they're closely-related things that're often (but not necessarily) used together.  With respect to .NET, most modern apps with a GUI are both asynchronous and multi-threaded.. but I think that may've been a good example of the thinking behind the question, since a lot of products advertise themselves as asynchronous, abstract multi-threading from the user (as .NET's `async` does).

Comment: @JimmyJames: As I understand it, a lot of programs used to be single-threaded.  Then when multi-threading got more popular, products started exposing threading.  But the early multi-threading interfaces left it to the user as to how to break up a workload across multiple threads.  So then later interfaces, e.g. .NET's `async`, instead asked the user to specify the synchronization points, splitting workloads up into `Task<>`'s, leaving the .NET-runtime to automatically handle the threading in the background.

Comment: @JimmyJames: So I could see why the OP (or an instructor of the OP) might think that async and multi-threading were different options, because they can seem like alternatives to a programmer being presented with the option of [using explicit-thread-management]-vs.[using an asynchronous framework], in which case it'd seem like the OP could've specified if they meant, say, manually interacting with `System.Threading.Thread` in .NET vs. using `async` in .NET.  But dunno if that's the actual context, or what else it might be.

Comment: @Nat They are alternate solutions to the problem of how to do IO without blocking other activities.

Comment: @Nat and if you are trying to fit some text on a page, switching the font family OR switching the font size are both potential solutions to that problem.  That makes them alternatives.